# SimpleBlobDetector not found in opencv 3.0 for python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use SimpleBlobDetector in python with cv2 version 3.0.
However when I run:

```
import cv2
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()
```

The console returns me:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SimpleBlobDetector'
```

Does anyone know if the function name has changed from cv2 version 2.4 to version 3.0?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The new function is `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)` if i'm not wrong.